# Increasing processor power of aws instance on demand

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have plex media server running on an aws instance. At this moment it will not use the GPU for transcoding so i am stuck with using the cpu. I am currently on c1.xlarge instance which works fine for me. I am going to be granting access to family and friends so this will not work if say on peak times (18:00 to 23:00 for example) i have more than 7 or 8 people trying to transcode and stream from the server at any one time. 
Is there any  way of increasing the compute power of this machine at certain times?
My thoughts as well when just writing this could be to create to seperate database for plex media server and use it to link to say c1.xlarge during the day and switch on c3.xlarge in the evening, but how could i keep these on the same ip, eg switch c1.xlarge off and switch c3.xlarge on?

Comment: Maybe the best solution for you is to contact Amazon with this question.

Comment: Think of using SQS or similar queueing system to put the work into tasks and preform them in sequence or in parallel (adding another machine in peak time)

Answer (score 0):

the moment you'll change the server you'll actually get anew server so the IP will change. you can use a load balance that will have the same IP/DNS and just add server (scale horizontally instead of vertically) using amazon auto scale(I think that you can also change the server type from there)

https://www.ezautoscaling.com/

Comment: Thanks this looks like it may be a solution for me. Will have a good look at it tomorrow. The site ezautoscaling looks interesting.